# Binded member call after delete

Tags: javascript

In this snippet delete returns true. So why f is being successfully called after delete?

```js
function X() {
    this.f = function() {
        console.log("X::f");
    }
}

x = new X;
var f = x.f.bind(x);
console.log("delete: " + delete x);
f();
```

Comment: how can you go past the line "var f...."? foo is not defined

Comment: Creates the object x in global scope i suppose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`delete` just removed the identifier `x`. The object still exists in memory, because it is bound to `f`.

`f` still refers to the same function with the same bound context, even though `x` doesn't.

See [the MDN page on `delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

> Unlike what common belief suggests, the delete operator has **nothing** to do with directly freeing memory (it only does indirectly via breaking references. See the memory management page for more details).